# kfifo vs list_head for queue implementation in Linux Kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, queue, kernel, fifo

What will be the pros and cons of using a kfifo or list_head for a FIFO queue implementation for a custom `struct` in kernel space ?

I am being inclined towards the use of `list_head` because it can be nicely embedded as a field within the `struct` that we want to use as a fifo queue node.

Comment: `kfifo` represents an array of only 2^n elements, `list_head` is a comprehensive double-list implementation with all facilities like inserting, deleting, traversing and so on. You can't remove an element in the middle of `kfifo`, for example. Better to read a corresponding Documentation in the source tree.